# Form Field Input One After Another

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I am creating a form wizard that guides the user through each form element, showing a tooltip describing each element.  What I am trying to accomplish is:

- Keep each form field disabled, excluding the form field the user is currently filling out.
- When the user wants to continue onto the next field, they need to click on the tooltip for the field they're currently on.  Also, the field needs to be non-empty to advance.

I have the tooltip appearing correctly, and it vanishes upon click.  What I can't figure out is how to say in JavaScript code: "Has the user entered data into the current field and clicked on the tooltip to advance?  Okay, then continue onto the next field until we've reached the submit button.  Otherwise, stay here on the current field."

Here is my code:

```
function prepareForm() {
  var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
  for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++){
      if (i !== 0){
          inputs[i].disabled = "disabled";
      }
      // Make sure the tooltip tag is present...
      if (inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0]) {
          inputs[i].onfocus = function () {
              this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "inline";
          }

          // When the user has entered information and clicked the tooltip, continue onto the next field.
          inputs[i].parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].onclick = function () {
              this.parentNode.getElementsByTagName("span")[0].style.display = "none";
          }
      }
  }
}
window.onload = prepareForm;
```

I've tried entering other logic in the onclick function, but because it gets executed at any time, I don't have access to the inputs array.  Any help on how I can accomplish this would be really appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: if you are open to use jQuery then this task would be easier.

Comment: I am open to jQuery.  Please feel free to suggest things from their API that would make this task easier.

Comment: @anu I understand jQuery can make DOM traversal quite simple, but can you recommend anything from the API that could solve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that you are comfortable with jQuery,I created [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/anupamsm/pGngj/) for you.As i dont know how are you showing the tool-tip,let me know if mine is not the one you are using.This example can help you start and add your own requirements.

Comment: The `<br />` breaks your code, as `next()` will get it instead of the proper element. Here is updated and correct code: http://jsfiddle.net/pGngj/8/

Comment: @shadow wizaed Tnx, i edited my fiddle.sorry i didnt check my work completely in the first place

Comment: your updated code still breaks if the `div` elements are not placed together. I strongly recommend using my code that free you from this dependency, by using the index of the clicked `span`.

Comment: @shadow wizard  yes i agree,but as we dont know what is the layout design he using so if he is placing the divs one below another then my code looks much simpler.However i agree,your code is much flexible and could be used for any layout design

Comment: @shadow wizard, I appreciate both of your code examples.  It helped solve my issue and reminded me that jQuery provides cleaner code for DOM manipulation.  @Shadow Wizard, why do you to mod arithmetic in your fiddle?

Answer (score -2):

I would ***not*** recommend this.  You are changing the default behavior of forms... with little or no benefit for the end user.

In addition you are forcing the users to do additional work between fields clicking on non-form field elements.

This fails basic usability and will only confuse users.  On a side note, if you haven't read "[Don't Make Me Think](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0789723107)" by Steve Krug please check it out at your earliest convenience - it is chock full of eye opening details about why "inventing" new UI concepts is often a bad idea.

**Update:** So I think its only fair that I provide a different recommendation based on the information given about this form being very much a hand-holding exercise.

Thus based on the *need* to control input field by field, I think the only way to do so in a usable way would be to provide this as a wizard, one field per page.  There are some added benefits to this in that if a decision is made in an early step that negates the need for a future step it can be omitted completely.

As a result I envision a form where there is a Previous/Next button at the bottom of each step (where applicable... e.g. step 1 would have no previous).  The Next button would start disabled and only enable itself when the user has put input into the field on that page.  When each step is shown, the focus should automatically be put into the field to enable quicker entry.

If possible, a progress bar or % complete indicator can be added to give the user a better understanding of how many steps remain.

#### Pros/Cons to this approach.

Pros:

- The user does not need to click anywhere to enable a valid transition to the next field
- No fields are disabled causing user confusion (except the Next button which is expected)
- The user can focus on the one field that matters at that moment (e.g. phone number) and there is plenty of room for instructions/help
- If step 1 is asking for say "Gender" and the user selects "Male" then step 6 that asks if the user has ever been pregnant can be skipped/auto-answered
- If the user wants to go back they can
- The user can't "accidentally" get to the next field without filling out the previous field
- The user will be familiar with this style/behavior of wizard, this is fairly typical of many wizards/installers

Cons:

- User can not see all questions at once
- User can not enter field values out of order
- User can not simply tab from field to field thus the overall form will be slower for advanced users vs. a single form

Comment: How can you assume so much without context? This may be an excellent way to guide the user in OP's application. Since we don't know what it is exactly, it's not fair to make these assumptions. Also does not answer the question directly, which is very clearly stated and has shown sufficient effort. It is also about javascript, not user interaction.

Comment: If the original poster wants I can provide the code to do it - however in my opinion designing UI for the past decade I've learned from experience that this is not a good idea.  What if I want to enter my email address first because I have it in my clipboard already?  When a user goes to click on a field to enter data they won't be able to.  Except for checkbox and radio buttons **most** users are not aware that clicking on a label focuses a form element (on the web)... and more importantly the behavior of clicking the label to make a field un-disabled is not common *at all*.

Comment: I hate to sound harsh - I'm just trying to be clear, but if I (as a user) had to use the system above as described I would be filing a bug report on the spot...  If the software wasn't fixed to enable the form to work like "normal" I would discontinue using the software - the usability issue for this screen is that big.

Comment: I agree with you, but I don't think we should take that advice as gospel. There are some situations where either the user needs extreme hand-holding, or the form/interface itself changes dynamically depending on the input. If you had code to share along with your opinion, I would've +1'd this.

Comment: If the OP wishes to provide more information (e.g. what the fields are that are being collected) that indicates why this scenario is special enough to warrant hand-holding, I think we can all provide a better, usable solution (with code) to guide the user step by step.

Comment: @scunliffe, I appreciate your feedback and in most cases I would whole heartedly agree with you.  In this case, however, the user needs to have their hand held every step of the way.  The tooltip will literally say (after the necessary directions), "Click here when you're finished."  Within the project, there is one form that allows autonomy, but this is a very detailed wizard.  If you'd like to recommend another solution with code, please feel free.  I'm open to all suggestions as long as it fits the requirements of the wizard.

Comment: @scunliffe The requirements state all form elements need to be on the same page.  I appreciate your feedback and the breakdown of pros and cons for your approach.

Comment: @webren - best of luck.  If there is a final version of this (public or private) I'd be curious to see how it works out.  Cheers, Steve